# How many times will each number be printed if the execvp() fails? I get C 3 times when running but my logic says C 2 times

Tags: c, for-loop, printf, buffer, fork

the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            printf("A");
            execvp("./prog2", &argv[1]);
            printf("B");
            exit(1);
        } 

        printf("C");
    }

    printf("D");
    return 0;
}
```

i expect something like this to happen(check photo), parent holds C into its buffer(first iteration) then holds CC after the second iteration and finally prints CCD, as for the children, first prints AB then exits same for the second one(second iteration). so i would say: A->two times, B->two times, C->two times and D->one time. But what i get when running it is:A->two times, B->two times, C->THREE times and D->one time. which is correct and why?(help would be much appreciated i have an exam soon)[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB6Kp.jpg)

Comment: [run it multiple times](https://godbolt.org/z/fPacr3EEE), the output is subject to race conditions.

Comment: @yano, the overall order of the output letters may change, but I don't see any reason to think that the counts of the various letters would do.

Comment: If it isn't obvious at a glance how many processes that are generated, then the correct answer is "the program is crap and should be rewritten". It is well-known that fork() has one of the most dysfunctional APIs ever created, so it is extra important that any use of that function is clear and unambiguous. Arguably there is no other correct use of it than to check the result, then call one of two never-returning functions from there.

Comment: my man believe me i know this. this is a past exam question. im preparing for my final exam. trust me not my fault the program is so messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i expect something like this to happen(check photo), parent holds C into its buffer(first iteration) then holds CC after the second iteration and finally prints CCD, as for the children, first prints AB then exits same for the second one(second iteration). so i would say: A->two times, B->two times, C->two times and D->one time. But what i get when running it is:A->two times, B->two times, C->THREE times and D->one time. which is correct and why?

The standard output is buffered by default, and the buffer lives in the process's memory.  Therefore, each time the parent process forks, **the child receives a copy of the parent's stdout buffer**, including any contents it holds at that time.

At the first fork, the parent's buffer is empty, but at the second fork, it contains the "C" that the parent printed at the end of the first loop iteration.  Both parent and (second) child will eventually print that "C", which accounts for the extra you observed over what you expected.  You could avoid that by inserting a call to `fflush(stdout)` at the bottom of the loop.

Assuming all `fork()`, `printf()`, and `exit()` calls succeed, and all `execvp()`s fail, we have the following evolution of the output buffer contents in the various processes:

|  | P1 | P2 | P3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1, 2 |  |  |  |
| 3 |  | AB |  |
| 4,5 | C | AB |  |
| 6 | C | AB | C |
| 7 | C | AB | CAB |
| 8 | CC | AB | CAB |
| 9 | CCD | AB | CAB |

1. P1 enters the loop as the only process, not yet having called `printf`.
2. P1 then forks P2, and in that iteration of the loop,
3. P2 `printf`s "A" and then "B", then exits.
4. P1 `printf`s "C".
5. P1 then cycles back to the top of the loop and `fork`s again.
6. P3, forked from P1, initially has "C" in its copy of the `stdout` buffer.
7. P3 `printf`s an additional "A" and "B", then exits.
8. P1 `printf` a "C", then its loop terminates.
9. Finally, P1 `printf`s a "D".

Each processes flushes its buffered output when it terminates.  The outputs from the various processes will not be intermingled, but groupwise, they can appear in any order.  For example,

```
ABCABCCD
```

Any way around, there should be a total of 2 As, 2 Bs, 3 Cs, and 1 D, exactly as you observe.

Comment: you ve been very helpful indeed. the code got me confused or i was distracted not properly observing that the parents buffered C is passed on the second child but you ve made that clear. thanks for your time.

Comment: one last question. if the execvp() does indeed succeed would we expect an output of something like: CCDAA because the buffer is being flushed out when execvp() is being executed(in the child process) or something like CCDACA?

Comment: @MikeBalts, for the same reason that the child process can inherit buffered output across a `fork()`, a successful call to one of the `exec`-family functions clobbers all streams' buffers.  They are part of the process image, and are replaced along with everything else in the process image when an exec is successfully performed.  If your particular `execvp()` calls succeeded, then, I would not expect to see only "CCD", plus the output printed by two runs of `./prog2`.  Everything else should either be clobbered or never be printed in the first place.

Comment: so it even wipes out the parents buffer? lets say ./prog2 doesnt print anything extra. what would you expect as an output if execvp() succeeds?

Comment: @MikeBalts, no, it does not wipe the parent's buffer.  Process isolation does not allow that, nor would it be desirable.  When I said "all streams' buffers" I meant that to be understood as being scoped to the process in which the `execvp()` call was performed. It wipes ("discards" would be a better term) all contents of the I/O buffers of the process that `execvp()`s, and indeed, the buffers themselves, too.  That does not affect the parent, but it does include any still-buffered data of the current process that was *inherited from* the parent.  I already commented on the resulting output.

Comment: Correction to prior comment: "I ***would*** expect to see only 'CCD', plus the output printed by two runs of ./prog2."